# Transformation between two optimization problems.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Problem $1$ is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\max_{1{\le}i{\le}N}\min_{\{v_i\}_{i=1}^N\in\textbf{V}_{\gamma}}\left[\lambda_i - v_i\right]
\end{equation}

Problem $2$ is as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&\max_{\textbf{y}\in{\Re}^N}\min_{\textbf{v}\in\textbf{V}_{\gamma}}\sum_iy_i(\lambda_i - v_i) \\
&\mbox{subject to} \sum_iy_i \le A, \\
&y_i \ge 0, \forall{i}
\end{eqnarray}

where $\textbf{V}_{\gamma}$ is a convex set, $\textbf{y}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are vector function with $N$ number of elements. There is a relationship between Problem $1$ and Problem $2$. I am wondering whether there is any way to trasform from Problem $2$ to Problem $1$, and vice versa. I would appreciate if anybody could help me on this.

Comment: No response! please at least try............

Comment: Is there any other forum from which I get the solution of my problem? Thanks